# Is there a difference in meaning when pronouncing paytronizing or pahtronizing?

Tags: pronunciation

I am not a native speaker, and I was recently corrected when pronouncing patronizing "paytronizing" when meaning condescending. I was told it is wrong to pronounce it that way; however, after looking it in dictionaries, I found both pronunciations to be accepted and no information on differences in usage.
Should I stop pronouncing it paytronizing? Does it have a different connotation/denotation when using one or the other pronunciation?

Comment: I guess the question should be titled _What is the correct pronunciation of patronizing?_ Words have a meaning, not their pronunciation.

Comment: Me, I've always thought that we paytronize a business, but pahtronize those to whom we feel superior. Oh, English.

Comment: Even words with the same pronunciation have the same meaning.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Well that's clearly wrong. If a word has a meaning, so does its pronunciation: the pronunciation is part of the word. What the question is really asking is whether the two verbs written _patronise_ (or _patronize_) are pronounced the same.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, /paytronizing/ is mainly American, /pahtronizing/ is British. Note that it is (usually?) written *patronising* with an *s* in British. I believe there is no commonly recognised distinction in meaning between the two pronunciations, as in /pay-/ meaning "condescending" v. /pah-/ for other senses, though some might disagree.

Comment: Both senses derive from 'acting as a patron towards...', in the older sense that a patron is a supporter or protector. Such a person might be haughty or condescending to his clients (who would have been his social inferiors). 
The later usage for a patron is someone who gives their regular business to a shop/hotel/etc., and so patronising in this sense has a more positive connotation.

Comment: @gpr: Oh, I see now that my sentence was ambiguous: I didn't mean to say that there were no different senses—just that there was no one-on-one correspondence between one pronunciation and one sense; I have corrected my answer above. Your explanation of etymology is excellent. I'd like to add that "patron" comes from Latin *patronus*, which comes from *pater*, "father". *Patronus* was used for a well-to-do man who had *clientes*, supporters, whom he sometimes provided with small favours, in return for which they then supported him as a crowd in elections and other things.

Comment: Interesting, I assumed that it would be a US/UK difference, but I can't recall hearing it with */pay-/* as the first syllable, must not often hear it used by Americans.  The word that is, not the action, if only.

Comment: @Orbling: Haha, I see. I am not sure how wide-spread /pay-/ is in America; I was merely offering my impression mixed with a few internet sources. I was hoping that perhaps someone might produce a map with isoglosses or something... Kosmonaut once showed me a map with the prevalence of *coke, pop, soda,* etc. for the same type of beverage, in countless coloured dots sprinkled across America forming oddly-shaped puddles.

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you go spreading such substances all over a continent.  Very difficult to clean, awfully sticky underfoot.

Comment: The first vowel is always either the /eɪ/ of *f**a**te* or else the /æ/ of *f**a**t*. It is never the /a:/ of *Genghis Kh**a**n*.

Answer (score 2):

The copies of the *NOAD* and *ODE* I had on my Mac Mini said that the pronunciation of *patronize* is /ˈpeɪtrəˌnaɪz/, /ˈpætrəˌnaɪz/ when using the American English IPA, and /ˈpætrənʌɪz/ when using the British English IPA; the first is the pronunciation in American English, the second is the pronunciation in British English.

Comment: [Both pronunciations](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronize) can be heard in the U.S.

Comment: That is what I said: The pronunciation I reported for American English is /ˈpeɪtrəˌnaɪz/, /ˈpætrəˌnaɪz/.

Comment: @Mari-LouA At the time, I always used the [_Dictionary_](https://macdownload.informer.com/dictionary/) application Mac OS X (now macOS) had. In the settings, where I chose the dictionaries to use, it didn't say it was a condensed version of [_OED_](http://www.oed.com/) (_Oxford English Dictionary_), nor could I understand that from the copyright notice.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't know where you get that, but it's the [_Oxford English Dictionary_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary): _The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) is a descriptive dictionary of the English language, published by the Oxford University Press._